# What's the significance of the union of all non-identity centralizers in a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let's assume we have a finite group G, where G contains ${e, g_1, g_2, g_3, ..., g_n}$, what would $C(g_1)\cup C(g_2)\cup C(g_3)\cup ...\cup C(g_n)$ be?

> Well, first, the centralizer of a group is defined as $C_G(S) = (g \in
>  G$ | $gs = sg$ for all $s \in S)$.
>
> Going from there, I've found that the answer is the subgroup all
>   elements in the group, assuming every element is its own centralizer
>   and e is always a centralizer too.
>
> There's also the intersection of the previous statement, i.e.
>   $C(g_1)\cap C(g_2)\cap C(g_3)\cap ...\cap C(g_n)$ - which I got to be
>   the subgroup of all elements in the group, since every element is its
>   own centralizer and so is $e$.

I'm assuming I did something wrong here, because it doesn't make sense that they're important yet I get the same result from both. Any ideas on how to go about solving this?

Comment: Are you saying that $e,g_1,\ldots g_n$ are all the elements?

Comment: @rschwieb Yeah, all the elements in the group G.

Comment: In general, $\bigcup_{e\neq g\in G}C_G(g)=G$ and $\bigcap_{e\neq g\in G}C_G(g)=Z(G)$, the center of the group. I'm just saying it has nothing to do with finiteness of the group or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think $C_G(S)=\{g\in{G}\;|\; gs=sg \text{ for all } s\in{S}\}$ would make much more sense: all the elements of $G$ that commute with every element of $S$. So we get:

$C(g_1)\cap...\cap C(g_n)$ is the set of all elements of $G$ that commute with every single $g_i$.

$C(g_1)\cup...\cup C(g_n)$ is the set of all elements of $G$ that commute with at least one of the $g_i$.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I fixed it. Can I ask how you reached the conclusion?

Comment: Well, usually one denotes $a\in{A},b\in{B}...$ etc. Apart from that, if it really were $s\in{G}$ in the definition of the set, then the $S$ wouldn't have any impact on that definition.

Answer (score 3):

If $G = \{ e, g_1, \ldots, g_n \}$, then the union of centralizers $C(g_1) \cup \ldots \cup C(g_n)$ is the whole $G$, as $g_i \in C(g_i)$.